# Migrate React web app to Electron

Tags: reactjs, electron

We are considering development of a web app using ReactJS (probably, we will use npm's create-react-app feature). Also, we are thinking if it will be possible in future to easily transform the web app to a desktop application using Electron. Since we have no experience with both technologies, we like to ask about this combination, whether it is a good option, and if it is possible to turn a React web app into a desktop Electron-powered app.

I was googling any working tutorial how to build an app using both technologies but no one worked for me.

So, to sum up, is it good choice to start developing a web app with React when we would like to have the opportunity to transform it into a desktop application built with Electron? If not, are there any better technologies?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You should look into how exactly your solutions are built, instead of focusing on the technology itself. If your team builds your backend with this in mind, you can create APIs that your clients(React Web App, Electron Desktop App) can connect to.

To answer the question: No, it is not a good choice to *begin development* of your web app project without considering future implications of your design. Focus your time on how your backend talks to your front end.

Moreover, ReactJS is only a front end library, you can use it with Electron, Check out some GitHub Hug Repos like: [Re-Electron](https://github.com/harshattray/Re-Electron)  , [React-Electron-Starter](https://github.com/alanbsmith/react-electron-starter), [Electron-React](https://github.com/tahnik/electron-react)

Comment: I think the question is asking if it's typically easy or hard to "wrap" a standard React app in Electron. The extreme cases would be, "it's so hard you basically need to rewrite the app" and "it's so easy, you just install some packages and configure them for a working Electron app build".